# how to remove space from ion-label while using with checkbox in ionic framework

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, checkbox, sass

I want to use checkbox, but there is blank space inside ion-label. i'm unable to remove space from ion-label. I want to display checkbox horizontally centre. my code is as below, can any one help me to solve this?

```
    <ion-item text-center no-lines>
        <ion-label color="secondary">
            keep me signed in
        </ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox item-right [(ngModel)]="Remember"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want is centered `ion-label` with sticky checkbox?

Comment: yes i want to set it to horizontally centre.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution is not fancy, but works.

In your corresponding ***.scss**

```
ion-item{
    .input-wrapper{
        flex:none;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
    ion-checkbox.checkbox{
        margin-right: auto !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hyuck Kang, why are you providing a solution SCSS? Maybe I skipped something but did the OP asked a solution specifically in SCSS?

Comment: OP asked about ionic3 which generally use scss as style.

Answer (score 0):

good morning hope this cloud help you

```
ion-item.item-input {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```